# How can I get visual studio text editor background colour?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

I want to be able to get the rgb colour of the back of the text editor in visual studio so I can use it in an addin so it goes with the theme the user has set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has modified the background font it will be stored here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\FontAndColors\{58E96763-1D3B-4E05-B6BA-FF7115FD0B7B}\Plain Text Background
```

If the user has not modified the color, you could key off of the theme they are using based on this registry value:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\General\CurrentTheme
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are after: IVsFontAndColorStorage interface

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsfontandcolorstorage.aspx

Comment: Except that will only work for a specific theme, VS2012 comes with 3 default themes.

Comment: Jesus, I frickin found how to read the ColorableItemInfo, how do I bloody get the final color out of the uint stored there???